# Different results when running shell command via ssh CLI vs. ssh shell

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I have some baffling behavior that I'm sure has a logical explanation, but I'm wasting a lot of time trying to figure out.

Basically I'm getting different results for `lsb_release -cs` when run in different contexts against a Debian compute engine instance.

For example:

```
$ gcloud compute ssh instance-1 --command "lsb_release -cs"
bullseye
$ gcloud compute ssh instance-1 --command "echo $(lsb_release -cs)"
focal
$ gcloud compute ssh instance-1
user@instance-1:~$ lsb_release -cs
bullseye
user@instance-1:~$ echo $(lsb_release -cs)
bullseye
```

What in the world? For some reason using `$(lsb_release -cs)` passed via `--command` yields `focal`, but everywhere else it yields `bullseye`.

Comment: I figured it out. `$(lsb_release -cs)` was being evaluated by my own shell before ssh executed it. Solution was to switch to single quotes: `gcloud compute ssh instance-1 --command 'echo $(lsb_release -cs)'`

Comment: Seems like your issue has been resolved. Can you please post your comment as an answer for the greater visibility of the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"$(lsb_release -cs)"` was being evaluated by the local shell before ssh executed it. 
Solution was to switch to single quotes: `gcloud compute ssh instance-1 --command 'echo $(lsb_release -cs)'`